# EvilZone barcode cracking on homepage

Tags: encryption, barcode, cracking

So i found this website called EvilZone and on their home page on the bottom there's a barcode, under it says "Can you crack it?" i'm new to the whole thing so i uploaded the image of the barcode to an online scanner and got this

```
64 57 64 6e 59 7a 6f 76 4c 33 42 31 62 6e 6c 35 63 6d 46 30 63 6d 59 75 63 6d 6c 32 65 57 31 69 59 58 49 75 59 6d 56 30 4c 31 39 66 5a 47 55 75 59 33 56 6a 0a
```

Then i decrypted the hex values using an online decryptor as well and got

```
dWdnYzovL3B1bnl5cmF0cmYucml2eW1iYXIuYmV0L19fZGUuY3Vj
```

i tried to decrypt that with MD5 and sha1 but it didnt work since the format is not right

Any idea on how to decrypt it ? i'm just curious

https://evilzone.org/images/emblem3.png

if this link doesnt work,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhEaF.jpg

Comment: This site is for programming related questions. But the answer to *Can you crack it?* appears to be *No, I can't. I have to go ask others to do it for me.*

Comment: Hint: base64 decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is:
`http://challenges.evilzone.org/__qr.php`

Simply take the result you currently have, which is base64, decode it, then the result of that is just a Caesar Cipher with a shift of 13.

Comment: yea thats as far as i've reached so far, Thanks to James K Polk for his hint, but when i visit the url i get a 404 error (Page not found)

its either the link is broken or the underscore (_) has a decryption which i dont know about